# Problem with method of arraylist.get(int i) in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I use TomCat, and I get an error "HTTP Status 500 - Internal server error, org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/login.jsp] at line [25]."
I do not understand why. Everything works perfectly, except the get (i) method of arryalist.
Here is the code:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>
      Registrazione
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <%! ArrayList<String> utenti = new ArrayList<String>(); %>
    <%!String u; %>

    <%
      ServletContext us = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
      ServletContext pw = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
      ServletContext cont = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
      //utenti.add(request.getParameter("usern"));
      //in base al username e password inseriti controlla se presenti dentro l'arraylist ed in caso positivo fa login, altrimenti no
      String use = request.getParameter("ulog");
      String pass = request.getParameter("plog");
      int conta=(int) cont.getAttribute("Conta");
      u = (String) us.getAttribute("Username"+conta);
      utenti.add(u);
      for(int i=0;i<=conta;i++){
        out.println(utenti.get(i));
      }
      out.println("USE " + use + "<br>");
      out.println("ARRAY " + utenti + "<br>");
      out.println("CONTA: " + conta);
      //out.println(cont.getAttribute("    Conta") + " " + us.getAttribute("Username"+conta));
    %>
      <a href="index.html"> CLICCA </a>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you initialize the u variable? `String u = "";` or `String u = null;`

Comment: FIrst : Could you add the log explaining the error ? it should tell you what the problem is, or at least help us to debug you. Second : Are you sure `conta` has a valid value ? If it's too big, you will face an IndexOutOfBoundExecption when trying to access an element of `utenti` that does not exist

Comment: @MustafaÇil it's useless, if you initialize it with `""` it will be overwritten, and initialize with null is done by default

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, its 
`ArrayIndexOutofBounceException`
mack sure that `conta` is always smaller than the size of `utenti`

or simply use

```
for(int i=0;i<Math.min(conta, utenti.size());i++){
        out.println(utenti.get(i));
      }
```

instead to avoid `ArrayIndexOutofBounceException`

Comment: To match the behaviour wanted, you should loop until the minimum between `conta` and `utenti.size()` => `Math.min(conta, utenti.size()`

Comment: @vincrichaud the variable conta has exactly the same size as the array.

Comment: @JoopEggen the variable counts has exactly the same size as the array.

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi seeing your code, the size of the array is always 1. How are you sure that conta is always 1 ?  Moreover, the problem was pointed by [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869507/problem-with-method-of-arraylist-getint-i-in-jsp/55869645?noredirect=1#comment98399458_55869645) as you were doing `<=`, which leads to OutOfBoundException